# Como puedo cambiar el color de fondo de una entrada cuando pulse un botón en 'Tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero cambiar el color del fondo de un 'entry' en tkinter con python pero al pulsar el botón no hace cambios ni tampoco da error.

Comment: Por favor pon el código que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Este código te permitirá cambiar el background del Entry, por un color aleatorio, cada vez que des clic en el primer botón. Si das clic en el segundo botón, se volverá blanco:

```
import tkinter
import random

window=tkinter.Tk()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()
entry.focus()

def cambiarColor():  
    color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
    entry.configure({"background": "#" + color})
    
def reset():  
    entry.configure({"background": "white"})

frame = tkinter.Frame(window, width=250, height=100)
frame.pack()

boton = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Clic', command = cambiarColor, width = 5, height = 3)
boton.place(x=50, y=10)

boton1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Reset', command=reset, width=5, height=3)
boton1.place(x=150, y=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno por mi experiencia en TCL, que es el lenguaje en el que se basa Tkinter, puedo decir que se podria crean un evento sobre el entry que dispare cambiarColor, como lo hace el boton 'Click'

```
entry.bind("<1>",cambiarColor)
```

Este evento del mouse <1> es cuando se hace click en el mouse con el boton principal, sinemargo la funcion CambiarColor, por ser un evento del GUI, devuelve 3 valores, el boton del mouse que se oprime, un x y un y que dependen de donde sea oprimido el click del mouse en el entry. estos valores que devuelve el evento solamente en python, deben ser guardado por la funcion en alguna variable, aunque no se use dentro de la función directamente, en TCL, no pasa asi, para ver esto mas en detalle, podriamos guardarlo en una variable 'a' e imprimirla print(a) para ver la respuesta del evento en la consola de python.

```
def cambiarColor(a):
print(a)  
color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
entry.configure({"background": "#" + color})
```

aunque ya con estos cambios en la funcion deberia funcionar el evento del mouse, al darle click sobre el entry deberia cambiar el color del fondo del entry. estos cambios ya no funcionan sobre el boton, porque en el boton no damos ningun valor con la funcion. En TCL el evaluador no necesita muchas cosas que python si exige.